# Grub not showing in Ubuntu/Windows dual boot fixed but not permanently

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have a dual boot UEFI system with Ubuntu 20.10 and Windows 10. When I turn on the PC the system boots straight into Windows 10. Following guides/posts on related issues I tried using this command (in windows cmd):

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

It worked and I was able to see GRUB and boot into ubuntu. The problem is every time I restart the PC I come upon the same issue and have to run the command again. I've tried running `$sudo update grub` in Ubuntu but it didn't work.

Is there a permanent solution to this problem?

Comment: Try using Boot Repair when you are booted into Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I used boot repair, but it rebooted directly into Windows anyways. I fixed by changing the boot manager location from Windows command line to \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi using the same command I first tried.